# How cache all pages in asp.net website?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to cache all pages in a website at first load. Actually i have a network monitoring system and dashboard of the monitoring system developing using asp.net.my intension is to cache all pages at the first time and when user navigate to pages , pages load from the cache. when i use this type of mechanism i can reduce bandwidth utilization . is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of MVC you can break down UI into smaller parts called Partial View.
Then you can Cache the View utilized in your Action method.

That will give you benefit of Optional caching / Cache options as well.